# Query Sql Server - Show blank line with other queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have a problem with the query below:

```
Select 'N' as Tipo,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Noleggio.DataInizioNoleggio, 105) as Data,DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Noleggio.DataInizioNoleggio) as GG,
Trasporto as CodArt,
Trasporto,Matricola,TipoMezzo,
'' as Totale
from Noleggio
```

[image]

Other than these parameters I have another one that is called - **DataTermineNoleggio**

I have to print under **DATA** the value of **DATAFINENOLLEGGIO** in an empty line containing only that parameter, I put an image of how it should be the result. How can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I guess you want to achieve:

```
select '',
   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Noleggio.DataTermineNoleggio, 105) as Data,
   '','','','','','' 
from Noleggio
```

But from I can understand, you want a way to show a 'start date' and an 'end date' for your row... wouldn't it be easier to:

```
Select 'N' as Tipo,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Noleggio.DataInizioNoleggio, 105) as DataInizio,
      CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), Noleggio.DataTermineNoleggio, 105) as DataTermine,
      DATENAME(WEEKDAY, Noleggio.DataInizioNoleggio) as GG, 
      Trasporto as CodArt,
      Trasporto,
      Matricola,
      TipoMezzo,
      '' as Totale 
from Noleggio
```

Comment: That's right, you understand, I know it would be easier the fact is that this is a part of a query (with different unions) in which the term -
  - DataTermineNoleggio- so the customer has asked me to print it this way

Comment: what language are you using to display the data? with my second statement you have all the information needed, you just have to format it 'the right way'.

Comment: Use c # and print report using microsoft reporviewer

Comment: the sql query is ok then. You should loop through the result of the query, and for each ítem create two rows: one row with all the info except 'DataTermine', and the second with just the DataTermine, placing it in the second column. You should create another question or modify this one with c# & reportviewer tags